# Конвертация из string в timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, timestamp

Есть массив:

```
a = [('2020-12-13 00:00', 'ADAM'), ('2020-12-13 01:00', 'MADAM'), ('2020-12-13 02:00', 'TADAM')]
```

Нужно добавить `Timestamp` в дату:

```
a = [(Timestamp('2020-12-13 00:00:00'), 'ADAM'), (Timestamp('2020-12-13 01:00:00'), 'MADAM'), (Timestamp('2020-12-13 02:00:00'), 'TADAM')]
```

Как это делать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `Timestamp` - это объект из Pandas, то это можно сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd

res = [(pd.Timestamp(x), y) for x,y in a]
```

результат:

```
In [145]: res
Out[145]: 
[(Timestamp('2020-12-13 00:00:00'), 'ADAM'),
 (Timestamp('2020-12-13 01:00:00'), 'MADAM'),
 (Timestamp('2020-12-13 02:00:00'), 'TADAM')]
```

---

или сначала сделать из списка фрейм, чтобы дальше с ним можно было работать в векторной форме:

```
In [149]: res = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["Date", "Name"]).assign(Date=lambda df: pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]))

In [150]: res
Out[150]: 
                 Date   Name
0 2020-12-13 00:00:00   ADAM
1 2020-12-13 01:00:00  MADAM
2 2020-12-13 02:00:00  TADAM

In [151]: res.dtypes
Out[151]: 
Date    datetime64[ns]
Name            object
dtype: object
```

Comment: как добавить Timestamp  в массив скажем с 4-5 индексами, динамично?